# Can’t write aggregate for protected type

Tags: ada, gnat

I have the following function

```ada
function Allocate(V : Value_Type; N : access Node) return access Node is
begin
    return new Node'(Value => V, Next => N);
end Allocate;
```

on compilation, GNAT complains about expecting an access to Node, yet finding a composite type. This seems broken.

Node is:

```ada
protected type Node is
    --Various routines
private
    Value : Value_Type;
    Next : access Node;
end Node;
```

I've reverted back to non tasking types, and don't have the exact error message. It's one I've seen numerous times when, for example, just using:

```
return (Value => V, Next => N);
```

or similar. I have never seen it when using "new Type'()".

Comment: Show us the declaration of Node, and the actual error message!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, there are no aggregates for protected types.  As Simon said in his answer, protected fields are private and are only visible within the body of the protected type (or possibly later in the private part of the protected type).  The outside world can't see the fields at all.  So you have to add a protected procedure to set the fields:

```
protected type Node is
    --Various routines
    procedure Set_Value(V : Value_Type);
    procedure Set_Next(N : access Node);
private
    Value : Value_Type;
    Next : access Node;
end Node;
```

and call the procedures in your `Allocate`:

```
function Allocate (V : Boolean; N : access Node) return access Node is
   New_Node : access Node;
begin
   New_Node := new Node;
   New_Node.Set_Value (V);
   New_Node.Set_Next (N); 
   return New_Node;
end Allocate;
```

(Or use an extended return as in Simon's answer--I think it will work.)

**NOTE:** I have not tested this.

The other possibility, if `Value` and `Next` will never change throughout the life of the protected object, is to use discriminants:

```
protected type Node (Value : Value_Type; Next : access Node) is ...
```

and now you can say

```
return new Node(Value => V, Next => N);
```

Note that there is no tick mark in this syntax!  I haven't tested this, though, so I'm not sure it will work.  I think it's acceptable to have a reference to the same type in the discriminant list, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The only place where `Value` and `Next` are visible (aside from the private part of `Node`’s spec, of course) is in their own `Node`’s body.

I can’t see a way of writing `Allocate` within `Node`. I gave up at

```
function Allocate (V : Boolean) return access Node is
begin
   return N : access Node do
      N := new Node;
      N.Next := Node'Access;
      N.Value := V;
   end return;
end Allocate;
```

having got messages along the way including

> `protected function cannot modify protected object`
>   `protected type cannot be used as type mark within its own spec or body` (so you can't say `Node'Access`)
>   `invisible selector "Value" for type “Node"`

so I think you’d need to use a wrapper of some sort.